# SSH public key not sending to server

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, key-authentication

I'm having difficult with the following, I'm trying to configure a cron job for rsync to sync between two serves, for which I need server A (local) to ssh into server B using a public key.

I previously added a passphraseless and passwordless connection by:

I. Setup PassPhrase Free with Key Agent via SSH

1. Restart SSH Key-Agent

   1. eval ssh-agent -s
2. Add private key

   1. ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_abc

#### Debugging Message

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS    
debug3: receive packet: type 21 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received    
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks    
debug2: key: /home/groups/user/.ssh/id_rsa_abc    (0x55ad08946370), explicit 
debug3: send packet: type 5 debug3:    receive packet: type 7 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received 
debug1:    kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>    
debug3: receive packet: type 6 
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth    
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
debug3: send packet: type 50    
debug3: receive packet: type 51 
debug1: Authentications that can    continue: publickey 
debug3: start over, passed a different list    publickey 
debug3: preferred    gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password    
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey 
debug3: remaining preferred:    keyboard-interactive,password 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering RSA    public key: /home/groups/user/.ssh/id_rsa_abc   
debug3: send_pubkey_test debug3: send packet: type 50 
debug2: we sent    a publickey packet, wait for reply 
debug3: receive packet: type 60    
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535 
debug2:    input_userauth_pk_ok: fp    SHA256:PYUC9QpfCGMZ8DOvOF944bFHchCNJyNRS2G+wjDXRKQ 
debug3:    sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA    SHA256:PYUC9QpfCGMZ8DOvOF944bFHchCNJyNRS2G+wjDXRKQ 
debug1:    read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address    
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key 
debug2: we did not send a    packet, disable method 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.    
Permission denied (publickey). ssh_exchange_identification:    
Connection closed by remote host ssh_exchange_identification:     
Connection closed by remote host 
rsync: connection unexpectedly    closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] 
rsync error: unexplained    error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

The public keys are in ~/.ssh/ (ie. /root/.ssh) and all file permissions are correct on both server A & B.

How I am running rsync command:

```
rsync -avP --stats --log-file=rsync.log -e 'ssh -p 22 -vvv' source_dir user@serverA:target_dir
```

Comment: It appears your keyfile is passphrase protected, is that correct? See the error `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`

Comment: Also, before trying `rsync`, just try to `ssh` alone to the target machine.